# ESP8266 vs ESP32 and WakeUp vs Reset

Tags: esp8266, gpio, sleep, gpio-external-interrupt

Maybe it's my fault but I kinda dislike the design of the ESP8266 when it comes to wakeup from deep sleep via an interrupt.

AFAIK (without an external circuit) the ESP8266 can not distinct between a WakeUp and a Reset. Especially not if the WakeUp signal is *bouncing* (alternating in very short periods).

**Question 1:** Is that true?

To state my problem in more detail:

My WakeUp signal is HIGH in general - so the ESP8266 will not wake up and that is okay. Then suddenly my WakeUp signal will start to *bounce*, so it will be LOW, HIGH, LOW, HIGH, LOW, [...] (for seconds or even minutes) until it will be high continuously again. I want to use that bouncing as **ONE** wakeup but since the pin for wakeup is the same as for reset it will reset the board over and over again.

What I read about ESP32 is that I'm able to choose the pin I like to use for my wakeup signal and so I can use one that isn't a Reset pin.

**Question 2**

We are in deep sleep on an ESP32 and there is bouncing on my choosen WakeUp pin (!= Reset). Does the following holds true:
The first LOW will wake up the board and all following switches from HIGH to LOW will be ignored by the board *until* it goes to sleep again.

**Question 3**

Is there some *simple* external circuit or even some code to achieve the behavior of Question 2 also on the ESP8266?

Thank you so much!

Comment: interesting post ... couple of questions ... what does this mean? `alternating in very short periods` ... don't forget that `short periods` have different meanings to a human and a microcontroller .... question 3 refers to behavior in question 1, but question 1 does not describe a behavior ... what behavior does question 3 refer to?

Comment: sorry! please see my edit. with "very short periods" I mean like "less time than loading the boards program"

Comment: `Then suddenly my WakeUp signal will start to bounce` ... it sounds like you are describing an undesirable occurence that is caused by the ESP8266 ... what generates the wakeup signal? ... what causes the bounce?

Comment: No, no, it's not the esp causing that signal! The bounce is the input on the wakeup/reset pin. To name it, it's a simple vibration sensor (but that's not part of the problem I stated). Thank you for your interest :)